# Circa late 70s - early 80s kids (television?) movie with hacking plot

Tags: story-identification, movie, tv, cyberpunk

This memory has been bugging me since I re-watched "Explorers" (1985) a few months ago: I realized that I had transferred memories from another movie onto the characters, and now I want to try to find the other movie they came from.

I can't remember anything about the title (over-written by "Explorers", I guess). Nor character names. I think I must've been pretty young -- about the age of the characters or slightly older. That makes the date roughly 1978-1982.

Features I do remember:

EARLY home-computing. Might have been a remote-terminal (which is more 70s tech).

The main character is a pre-teen boy, supported by another pre-teen boy sidekick.

The main character is presented as a classic "boy genius"/"geek" character, with mostly an engineering/electronics/computers focus (they would not have used the term "geek" or "hacker" at that time -- those are later terms, but they would apply to the character from our perspective).

The central plot involves an electronic break in to a local bank. I think this was a technical exploit that allowed them to get in and out of the bank, physically, involving electronic or computer access.

But this is an early example of the "pen-testing" idea, as the boy defends his actions by saying he was "just trying to show it could be done" (and in the way of privileged youth, this works for him).

The sidekick character had the notable characteristic of making the "ching-ching-ching ching-ching-ching" sound effect from "The Six Million Dollar Man" when he ran (I totally knew kids in real life who did this. It was a popular show).

The MOST unique feature I remember is a brief conversation involving the preposterous idea that this kid had given his rabbit a bionic limb. I cannot remember if this was supposed to already have happened, or if they were just planning it. I do remember a diagram or fake X-ray prop.

I watched this on TV, probably at the time it was released. So it may have been a made-for-TV / television movie, rather than a theatrical release. But I remember it being feature-length and stand-alone (not part of a series).

It can't be much before 1978, because it references home computer technology that wasn't around until 1977 or so (if he used a terminal, that might push it back slightly). Styles of hair and clothes were appropriate to that late-70s, early-80s era. And it can't be much after 82, because I would remember feeling "too old for it" (as I did feel about "Explorers"), whereas this movie hit me pretty close to where I was at the time (I was near the target age group).

Comment: Hmm... an actual bionic limb would be sci-fi. Are there any actual sci-fi aspects?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because there are no actual science fiction or fantasy aspects provided other than a kid making Bionic Man noises and a hypothetical bionic limb for a rabbit.